# glReadPixels returns a blank image on disabling blend

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing the same texture twice; one on top of the other. The second texture is zoomed in, to create a picture in picture effect.
I'm using the same vertex and fragment shaders, and the same reference to them.

With `glEnable(GL_BLEND)`, the output looks like (undesirable):[image: enabled]

With `glDisable(GL_BLEND)`, the output looks like this (desired): [image: disabled]

But, on performing `glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);`, with `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` I get a completely black image with some random strokes towards the edges of the image (plus the timestamp comes out fine).

Edit 1: the output I get is:
[image]
Note, I convert the byte buffer to a bitmap, and then a jpeg.

Why might `glReadPixels` be returning a black output and how do I fix this?

EDIT 2:
Alright, even on setting `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` with the blending function `GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ZERO);`, that displays the desired output, I get the same black/blank output on `glReadPixels`. This means this might not have anything to do with blending, but maybe the fact that I'm using the same program (fragment+vertex) to draw the two on each other. Extremely clueless at this point.

Comment: Are you sure you get a completely black image, not a completely transparent one? Could you upload it?

Comment: Updated with the output. I'm converting it to jpeg, so I'm not really sure about transparency.

Comment: Make sure you're calling `glReadPixels()` before `eglSwapBuffers()`. Otherwise you'll read from the "empty" buffer you just swapped to.